# How to use the select menu value in the specific DIV jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following code to get the selected item value and post it to a DIV. That is okay, it is working fine, my DIV shows the selected value. But my question is how can I use that value in the DIV ? so that I can create a php msyql query.

```
<head>
<style>
.response {
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#9F9;
    border:2px solid #396;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#developer").change(onSelectChange);
});
function onSelectChange(){
var selected = $("#developer option:selected");
var output = "";
if(selected.val() != 0){
output = selected.val();
}

$("#output").html(output);
$('#output').slideDown("slow");
}
</script>
</head>

<select id="developer">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">name</option>
<option value="2">name2</option>
</select>

<div align=center class=response id=output style="display:none;">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("err");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$age = $row[age]; }
echo $age;
?>
</div>
```

Comment: There are lots of efficient ways to get data to javascript. In order to help, I'd need to know some details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, the post has been updated, the code is now available. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript executes on the front-end, in the user's browser.  PHP and mysql are executed on the backend, on your server.  If you want to use values from your javascript in PHP and mysql, you will need to make a request to the back-end.

You should read up on

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

and/or

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: So there is no way to get the php detect the data in a div without posting it with ajax or jquery post ? I simply wanted this select menu >> post the selected value to a div >> create a php mysql query in the div by using the selected value.

Comment: This is not possible without hitting the backend.  As I explained, you really need a better understanding of how and where everything is working.  Javascript is run on the client machine, php and mysql are on the server.  If javascript needs to communicate with php or mysql a request needs to be made to the backend.  Php and mysql are not run on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is that you submit the form or send an ajax request back to your server.  Your server using PHP, in your case, uses that data to form the DB query.

I think that you are mixing up the timing for when this code is being run.

1. PHP process and sends to Html loads
2. Javascript runs (hopefully after
3. HTML loads) Request is submited from
4. HTML or Javascript Back to the top

Comment: So there is no way to get the php detect the data in a div without posting it with ajax or jquery post ? I simply wanted this select menu >> post the selected value to a div >> create a php mysql query in the div by using the selected value.

Comment: There is no way. You are executing the code in a browser.  The database is on a server.  Something has to connect the two.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `$("#output").text(output)` instead of `$("#output").html(output)`.
Then you can use `$("#output").text(output)` to get the value your need.

Comment: Well I have tried $("#output").text(output) as well, the result is the same. I do know something is missing, something I have to change. Unfortunately I dont know how to assign the value to php in the div as the div only shows the selected menu value.

Comment: I know your meanings probably.I think you must send the value your want via ajax instead of writing a php code in the same file.

Comment: So there is no way to get the php detect the data in a div without posting it with ajax or jquery post ? I simply wanted this select menu >> post the selected value to a div >> create a php mysql query in the div by using the selected value.